# $state.go not executing inside controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to redirect a user to a login page if they are not currently logged in:

```
var user = Session.checkSession();
if(user){
  $scope.session.user = user;
} else {
  // redirect to login page
  $state.go('access.signin');
}
```

$state is injected into this controller correctly, because if I put `dummy.state` instead of `access.signin` I get the error:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'dummy.state' from state ''
```

`$state.go('access.signin')` is used successfully elsewhere in the app, so doesn't look like there's anything wrong with the route. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you submit a plunker to demonstrate the problem? In the meantime, try using $state.transitionTo in place of $state.go.

Comment: Your state configuration within your `app.js` would also be helpful